# Three.js benchmark, how to?

Tags: time, statistics, three.js, webgl, benchmarking

I'm about to perform some benchmark experiments for WebGL (Three.js). I'm thinking about loading time (from link click to loaded scene), loading time for files, and frame rate.

With many tests I must gather statistics which can be put into diagrams. All I have now is a FPS counter. Are there some good scripts to use for this?

What I need is a way of saving fps number each frame to a text file.
And time counters for loading scene and files.

Please help!